# Wordpress the_content() Not Working on Static Front Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes

I'm working on the theme for a Wordpress site I'm developing, and for some reason `the_content();` function isn't displaying anything on my static front page.  Furthermore, `the_title();` function only displays the word "Home" without displaying the actual title from the post.  Everything works fine in `single.php`, so I know the code itself isn't faulty, but I'll post it anyway as a formality.  I've tried disabling all plugins, that wasn't the issue.  This code worked fine on a previous version of this site I was working on, although the homepage on that site was `home.php` instead of `front-page.php` (I don't know if that would affect this or not).  If anyone can provide any suggestions, please help, since I'm basically out of ideas at this point.

```html
<?php if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    
        <div class="news-title">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
    
        <div class="news-body">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
     
    <?php endwhile; 
endif; ?>
```

Comment: I would confirm your **Settings > Reading** settings are set up properly, and your content doesn't have any broken code or shortcodes in it, and then take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display) documentation to make sure your relations between `front-page.php`, `home.php`, `page.php`, and `index.php` are correct

Comment: Everything seems to be set up correctly.  There's no broken code I can find and I'm not using any shortcodes.  I've gone ahead and set up a separate home.php page to function as a posts archive page (previously I hadn't created one yet), but that still hasn't resolved the issue.  I'm honestly ready at this point to just do a fresh install of WordPress and start moving stuff over piece by piece at this point, because for the life of me I can't figure out why such a basic function isn't working.